# How to remove all chart axis and labels from Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

[image]

I'm using following code, but still can't get rid of horizontal axis and labels.

```
    var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 0,
        color: 'none'
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 0,
        color: 'none'
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, google charts uses `vAxis`, with a V, instead of `yAxis`, for the "vertical" axis options.

what you have will work to remove the gridlines, by changing the above.

to hide the baseline, set `baselineColor: 'transparent'`

as for the labels --> `textPosition: 'none'`

```
var options = {
  legend: 'none',
  tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
  hAxis: {
    gridlines: {
      count: 0
    },
    textPosition: 'none'
  },
  vAxis: {
    baselineColor: 'transparent',
    gridlines: {
      count: 0
    },
    textPosition: 'none'
  }
};
```